# How can I load tf.js CDN in chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-chrome-extension, nlp

I am making a Machine-learning Chrome Extension so I need to use Tf.js but when I'm loading tf.js CDN it's given me an error?

```
Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

manifest.json

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"mainfest_version":2
```

background.js

```
const urls = {
  model:
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/sentiment_cnn_v1/model.json",
  metadata:
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/sentiment_cnn_v1/metadata.json",
};

// load model
async function loadModel(url) {
  try {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
    console.log("model Loaded");
    return model;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// load meta data
async function loadMetadata(url) {
  try {
    const metadataJson = await fetch(url);
    const metadata = await metadataJson.json();
    console.log("Metadata Loaded");
    return metadata;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- load tf.js model -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
```